# no such module '__ObjC' - Xcode 14.3 Update

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After debugging a lot seems like latest Xcode 14.3 version have complier changes & Archive is breaking with below errors & screenshot attached :-

[image]

```
/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-ccdlwtnmnbyewmdrzhbsqlqsqprc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxxx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/xxxxx/Release-iphoneos/xxxxx/Objects-normal/arm64/XXXX.private.swiftinterface:16:19: error: no such module '__ObjC'
@_exported import __ObjC
                  ^
/Users/shreeganesha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxx-ccdlwtnmnbyewmdrzhbsqlqsqprc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxxx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/mxxxxxxx.build/Release-iphoneos/xxxxxx.build/Objects-normal/arm64/xxxxxxxx.private.swiftinterface:1:1: error: failed to verify module interface of 'xxxxxxx' due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
// swift-interface-format-version: 1.0
```

Tried to update IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 12.4 but still the error is not fixed.

Comment: were you able to fix it? I am also getting the same error, in my project which is build in flutter

Comment: We have downgraded to Xcode 14.2 in the meantime